# Undersampling is not improving precision for binary classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, precision-recall

A snippet of my code-

```
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=20000, n_features=8, n_informative=6,
                        n_classes=2,weights=[150/151, 1/151],n_redundant=2,
                       n_clusters_per_class=3, class_sep=1.5, random_state=1729)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
LogisticRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
training_score = cross_val_score(LogisticRegression(), X_train, y_train, cv=5)

log_reg_params = {"penalty": ['l1', 'l2'], 'C': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000]}

grid_log_reg = GridSearchCV(LogisticRegression(), log_reg_params)
grid_log_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)

log_reg = grid_log_reg.best_estimator_

log_reg_score = cross_val_score(log_reg, X_train, y_train, cv=5)

sss = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, random_state=None, shuffle=False)

for train_index, test_index in sss.split(X, y):
    print("Train:", train_index, "Test:", test_index)
    Xtrain, Xtest = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    ytrain, ytest = y[train_index], y[test_index]

for train, test in sss.split(Xtrain, ytrain):
    pipeline = imbalanced_make_pipeline(RandomUnderSampler(sampling_strategy='majority', random_state=42), log_reg) # SMOTE happens during Cross Validation not before..
    model = pipeline.fit(Xtrain[train], ytrain[train])
    prediction = model.predict(Xtrain[test])
```

I have used sci-kit make_classification method to create various levels of imbalance datasets. Then I am applying resampling techniques to see their effectiveness. Based on the research I did, precision always improves at the cost of recall when undersampling is applied, but it did not occur in my case. The performance of undersampling is very similar to no resampling. I want to know if I have made some errors in code or the reason for the performance of undersampling.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: On Stack Overflow (actually, all of the Stack Exchange Network), questions must be self-contained. The primary purpose of Stack Overflow is for questions to be useful to future visitors. Questions which *require* users to go to off-site links in order to have the context needed to answer are not useful to future visitors. This question might be good/useful, if the off-site information is moved into the question. Note that if that content isn't yours, you need to comply with the [referencing requirements](/help/referencing) in addition to any copyright concerns.

Comment: Ok I will remove the kaggle notebook link then and add the code. Will that work? Edit- I have updated the question, is this fine now?

Comment: SInce you have [reposted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63544229/undersampling-is-not-improving-precision-for-binary-classification-using-make-c) the question after editing, please **delete** this one, otherwise you run the danger for the new one to be closed/deleted as a duplicate.

Comment: ok deleting the old one